# Emergency - our site down for 2 days. Ready to deploy on a new server but missing custom options; any way to put same custom options on all products?

Tags: custom-options, importexport, memory, magento-1.9.4.0, memory-leak

```
Magento 1.9.4
```

Our old Magento store (1.9.1) hosted at Hostforweb just stopped working (long story - first it was extremely slow = unusable; then the hosting company says they can move it to another node, which they did and the pages would not even load so now they are moving it back but we have been DOWN for days).

We have another hosting account with another company. I managed to set everything up and import all products via the Dataflow Import but this Dataflow import does NOT import custom options at all. I tried to do a regular Export/Import but it does not work - it says it's ready to import but then hangs at Please Wait.

The import file has 137 KB in size

According to our new hosting company:

> 22-Feb-2019 22:57:55 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of
>   2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in
>   /home/oursite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
>   on line 101

=============================

This is a real emergency for us and we need to switch the domains to the new host where a site is all ready but missing custom options on products.

**Is there an easy way to set up the very same custom options on all 1050 products?**

Comment: Why can't you get a dump of your database from the old server and just import it in the new one? The error suggests you have some very large files there.

Comment: @Zefiryn Is that going to be compatible? The file I'm trying to import only has a few columns = the SKU and the custom options, it's a standard CSV file generated by the same Export utility on Magento 1.9.1. Nothing large about that - just text all in all around 140 KB.

Comment: If you want to move your entire shop then it is far easier to just copy database than doing export in the old server and imports in the new. Plus you will get to keep customers, their passwords and order history.